# Create offer has no _effect_

Tags: manageofferoperation, effects

I issued a new *sausage* token and gave 1000 sausages to my other account in some shady barbecue related dealings. This other account issued [an offer to sell 500 SAUSAGE at a rate of 0.33 XLM per sausage](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/110eb1ff04754da9d9b2122f7d2cee8f403844ea67e7738e2f4ea4e89dd33f38/operations).

Apparently there are [no effects](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/operations/30985603470331905/effects) as a result of this. The documentation says [I should see an offer created effect](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/effect.html#trading-effects). Have I done something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effects `Offer Created`, `Offer Updated`, and `Offer Removed` are described in API docs, but not yielded by the Horizon. Check the [bug description](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/166) for more details.